# freeopcua python, unable to call method

Tags: python-3.x, opc-ua

I'm trying to call a method on an opcua server, the method is inside:

objects -> Commands -> FileManagement

as you can see better from the picture below

[tree opcua](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkq8P.png)

i'm using this code to call it

```
root = client.get_root_node()
command = root.get_child(["0:Objects", "0:Commands"])
filem = command.get_child("0:FileManagement")
method = filem.get_child("0:LoadFile")
argument = [ua.Variant("S:\filetoload.txt",ua.VariantType.String)]

res = filem.call_method(method, *argument)
```

but i get this error: (2147483648,)
i think it's just Bad result

the method only have one argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "S:**\\**filetoload.txt" instead of "S:\filetoload.txt" ?